# Deploy website on a different machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I created a website I need to deploy on a different server. We only have teamviewer to access this server.

With just being able to copy the files over to the server, how would I go about getting it running?

Comment: On what server / web server are you going te deploy?

Comment: will be windows server 2012 and im developing on windows 7, both are 64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publish site on local machine and upload the published folder on remote machine using filezilla. IIS has c:\inetpub\wwwroot as default website published folder. You may also see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: This is what I have done, just making sure I'm using the right procedure.